# How to switch the tabs in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to switch the tabs from one tab to other and need to switch back on previous tab.

So, please guide me for same.

Comment: It works like new windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
 String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

    // Perform the click operation that opens new window

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("yourElement").click());
    // Switch to new window opened
    for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }

    // Perform the actions on new window

    // Close the new window, if that window no more required
    driver.close();

    // Switch back to original browser (first window)
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```